# Google visualization chart not filling 100% of parent div

Tags: google-visualization

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?  (...your help is always very much appreciated!)

My google chart is not filling the parent div fully and I can't seem to figure out why.

Here are the chart options I'm using in my function:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'ComboChart',
    'containerId': 'div_chart_' + element_suffix,
    'view': {
        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    },
    'options': {
        allowHtml: true,
        width: '100%',
        height: 500,
        legend: {
            position: 'right',
            textStyle: { fontSize: 12 }
        },
        tooltip: {
            isHtml: true
        },
        hAxis: {
            type: 'category',       //converts continuous axis to discrete
            slantedText: true,
            slantedTextAngle: '90',
        },
        vAxis: {
            minValue: 0,
        },
        seriesType: 'bars',
        isStacked: true,        
    },
});
```

Parent div is 100% width:
[image]

Chart div is 100% width:
[image]

There is some kind of white space here I can't tell how to eliminate:
[image]